# Is completeness relation of polarization vector equivalent to propagator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

For the Proca Lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}+\frac{1}{2}m^{2}A_{\mu}A^{\mu}$$

the equation of motion is:
$$\Box A^{\mu}-\partial^{\mu}\partial_{\nu}A^{\nu}+m^{2}A^{\mu}=0$$

The classical plane wave solution is:
\begin{equation}
    A^{\mu}=\int \frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}}  \sum_{i=1}^{3} \epsilon_{i}^{\mu}(p)e^{ipx}
\end{equation}
the polarization vector satisfy:
\begin{equation}
    -p^{2}\epsilon^{\mu}-p^{\mu}p\cdot \epsilon+m^{2}\epsilon^{\mu}=0
\end{equation}
In the particle rest frame:
\begin{equation}
    p=(m,\vec{0})
\end{equation}
the polarization vector satisfy condition:
\begin{equation}
    k\cdot \epsilon=0
\end{equation}
choosing a orthonormal basis such that:
\begin{equation}
    \epsilon^{i}\epsilon^{j}=-\delta^{i k}
\end{equation}
by Lorentz invariantce, it is true in all inertial frame.

The completeness relation of polarization vectors are must satisfy the form:
\begin{equation}
P_{\mu \nu}=\sum_{i=1}^{3}\epsilon_{\mu}^{i}\epsilon_{\nu}^{i}=A\eta_{\mu \nu}+Bp_{\mu}p_{\nu}
\end{equation}
then using the Lorentz Gauge condition:
\begin{equation}
    P_{\mu \nu}p^{\mu}=0 \rightarrow A=Bm^{2}
\end{equation}
also using the orthonormal basis condition:
\begin{equation}
    P_{\mu \nu}\epsilon^{\nu j}=-\epsilon_{\mu}^{j}=A\epsilon_{\mu}^{j} \rightarrow A=-1
\end{equation}
therefore the completeness relation is:
\begin{equation}
     P_{\mu \nu}=\sum_{i=1}^{3}\epsilon_{\mu}^{i}\epsilon_{\nu}^{i}=-(\eta_{\mu \nu}+\frac{p_{\mu}p_{\nu}}{m^{2}})
\end{equation}
which is also the projection operator.

Nonetheless, if we start from the equation of motion:
\begin{equation}
    \Box A^{\mu}-\partial^{\mu}\partial_{\nu}A^{\nu}+m^{2}A^{\mu}=0
\end{equation}
which can be recast as:
\begin{equation}
    [g^{\mu \nu}(\partial^{2}+m^{2})-\partial^{\mu}\partial^{\nu}]A_{\nu}=0
\end{equation}
Fourier transform the equation becomes:
\begin{equation}
    [g^{\mu \nu}(-p^{2}+m^{2})+p^{\mu}p^{\nu}]A_{\nu}(p)=G^{\mu \nu}A_{\nu}=0
\end{equation}
Let the propagator be:
\begin{equation}
    G_{\nu \lambda}=Ap_{\nu}p_{\lambda}+Bg_{\nu \lambda}
\end{equation}
where it satisfy the relation:
\begin{equation}
    G^{\mu \nu}G_{\nu \lambda}=\delta_{\lambda}^{\mu}
\end{equation}
then plugging in the ansatz:
\begin{equation}
    (-p^{2}+m^{2})p^{\mu}p_{\lambda}A+B(-p^{2}+m^{2})\delta_{\lambda}^{\mu}+Ap^{2}p^{\mu}p_{\lambda}+Bp^{\mu}p_{\lambda}=\delta_{\lambda}^{\mu}
\end{equation}
which gives:
\begin{equation}
    G_{\nu \lambda}=\frac{1}{-p^{2}+m^{2}}(g_{\nu \lambda}-\frac{p_{\nu}p_{\lambda}}{m^{2}})
\end{equation}
so here is the hint, if I switch $$g_{\nu \lambda} \rightarrow -\eta_{\nu \lambda}$$ as transverse mode is only involved, which is spatial, ignore the denominator as I demand orthonormal basis. Is it a valid way of starting from the propagator, then to the inverse process to obtain the completeness relation of polarization vector?

Comment: why not? the completeness is used to find out the propagators.